# Cpp, enforcing a preprocessor evaluation order

Tags: c++, c++17, preprocessor

Given the following snippet of code, with preprocessor trickery in every .h and .cpp file, is it possible to evaluate the associated preprocessor functions in the order the functions are called in? How could I enforce that whitout a lot of difficulty for the programmer who has to maintain this?

```
#include "Foo.h"
#include "Bar.h"
#include "Qux.h"

int main()
{
    Foo foo = Foo();
    Bar bar{};
    foo.doFoo();
    Qux::doQux();
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: 
Some clarification, let's assume Foo, Bar, Qux .cpp and .h declare preprocessor defenitions.
Can I enforce Foo.h, Foo.cpp, Bar.h and Bar.cpp are evaluated before Qux.h by the preprocessor?

Comment: The preprocessor runs before the compiler. The preprocessor doesn't know what a function call is, the compiler runs too late to intervene. Preprocessor functions/macros are evaluated the moment they're read, usually because of an `#include`.

Comment: What do you mean by "evaluate the associated preprocessor functions in the order the functions are called in"? What does the example code have to do with the question?

Comment: @bathsheba I do `#include` myself whenever I'm not invited to a party and crash it, that's true

Comment: @SombreroChicken: Do you crash it because of undefined behaviour, or due to a failed penetration test?

Comment: @bathsheba Aren't all successful penetration tests undefined behavior? Resulting in spawning a child process or not depending or the architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I enforce Foo.h, Foo.cpp, Bar.h and Bar.cpp are evaluated before
>   Qux.h

You can enforce inclusion of `Foo.h` and `Bar.h` before `Qux.h`, one way of doing that:

1) Put at the beginning (or even end) `Foo.h`:

```
#ifndef FOO_H_INCLUDED
#define FOO_H_INCLUDED
#endif
```

2) Put at the beginning (or end) `Bar.h`:

```
#ifndef BAR_H_INCLUDED
#define BAR_H_INCLUDED
#endif
```

(the above can actually also serve as inclusion guard, if you want to have it)

3) Check in the `Qux.h`:

```
#ifndef FOO_H_INCLUDED
#error Please include Foo.h before Qux.h!
#endif

#ifndef BAR_H_INCLUDED
#error Please include Bar.h before Qux.h!
#endif
```

The other way - simply add to beginning of `Qux.h`:

```
#include "Foo.h"
#include "Bar.h"
```

That enforces that `Foo.h` and `Bar.h` are always processed before the rest of `Qux.h` (without having to check for the inclusion defs).

`Foo.cpp` and `Bar.cpp` have nothing to do with that, those are separate translation units build in a separate compiler (and preprocessor) run.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I enforce Foo.h, Foo.cpp, Bar.h and Bar.cpp are evaluated before
>   Qux.h by the preprocessor?

Not via the preprocessor, no.  The usual way to enforce a parse-ordering like that is via `#include` directives -- for example, if you want to guarantee that `Foo.h` and `Bar.h` are always parsed before `Qux.h`, then add `#include` lines at the top of `Qux.h` to guarantee it:

```
// Qux.h
#ifndef QUX_H
#define QUX_H

#include "Foo.h"
#include "Bar.h"

[...]

#endif
```